# C++ cin.getline only reads one character

Tags: c++, getline, cin

I'm using Xcode 4.5 and I have the following code in my program:

```
char strChar[5];
cin.getline(strChar, 5);
int i = atoi(strChar);
```

When I start to try and enter a number, after the first number is pressed, the console will not accept any more input (other than the enter key, in which case the program just returns zero straight away). Obviously, I want to accept more than one character, how can I accomplish this?

Thanks for answering my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*******UPDATE*********** 10/04/2012*********

**APPLE HAS RELEASED AN UPDATE THAT FIXES THIS ISSUE. XCODE 4.5.1 (4G1004)**

This is a known bug in Xcodes newest release (4.5). Apple knows about it and is working on a patch. Currently at press time, there is no known work around. For now you just have to run the program in Terminal.

** Note in newer versions of Xcode, the command line tools are not installed automatically **
 To Install Go Into Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> *Install the command line tools*

To Run C++ Programs in Terminal:

1.) Open Terminal.

2.) Navigate to the correct directory

3.) type "make projectName" minus the quotes

4.) Execute Program: "./projectName" minus the quotes

Comment: Best I can manage, hoping Apple resolves quickly, it's definitely a pain..lol

Comment: @JamesPrince Download the Update

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read one line, it's probably easier to write: std::getline(std::cin, str), where str is of type std::string.
Your example reads only 5 characters.

Note: If you want to read not just 1 number, but a bunch of numbers on multiple lines, you should put this all into a loop.

Comment: I have the same behaviour if I use that code, the console basically freezes after the the first character (but xcode doesn't crash or anything)

Answer (score 1):

just a note: your code did not read the string into "str", just "strChar".

Comment: I was just playing around with the code and it ended up looking like that, i'll change it to make more sense.